# Как перевести unix timestamp в обычную дату/время(с секундами)

Tags: javascript, unixtimestamp

Здравствуйте, пишу код на Javascript. Задача такая - надо перевести время из unix timestamp в обычную дату/время (с секундами) и желательно получить каждое значение по отдельности(день, год, месяц, час и т.д.)

Answer (score 3):

Нашел на англ Stackoverflow:

```
function timeConverter(UNIX_timestamp){
  var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  var year = a.getFullYear();
  var month = months[a.getMonth()];
  var date = a.getDate();
  var hour = a.getHours();
  var min = a.getMinutes();
  var sec = a.getSeconds();
  var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;
  return time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы ищете `Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`. Пример из [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

```
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
let options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleString('de-DE', options));
// → "Donnerstag, 20. Dezember 2012"
```